# Session login on phone App

Tags: php, javascript, html

I will try to ask the question as best as I can... Sorry if it not so much clear.

When I create a login form on a website, the backend retrieve a $_SESSION variable (PHP) with the user ID, and some info from the database. I call this variable with session_start() and I can check privileges and so on.

If I perform this on an phone app (HTML5), all code is on the device, and I have no of server's session... How can I maintain this session? Do I have to store something on the device and send it on each post request? I am a bit confused about this... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No. The phone app is on JS + HTML5. The PHP is on the server, but I don't know how to protect the post from a phone.

Comment: Sessions ... should still work.

Comment: In your case, there's no practical difference between your app running on a phone, and your app running on a desktop browser.

Comment: Thanks. The difference will be if I write an app on Java (Android) or O-C (IOS) right?

Comment: Yes, if you write a native app you have to do things a little bit differently.  It is still technically possible to maintain a session with a PHP server app but you have to switch to passing the session ID in the URL.  Whether or not that's a good idea is another matter entirely.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But passing the ID on the url won't be dangerous?

Comment: It's very dangerous for a normal web app because people can easily paste URLs with their session ID somewhere public and have it hijacked.  Less dangerous if URL is not exposed to user.

Comment: This only applies if your native app is trying to communicate with PHP server somewhere and needs to maintain a session with it.  Session may not be very useful for native app.

Comment: The idea is to retrieve data from the server's database (PHP + Mysql), but I never try it from a Java app.